# Can't Deploy Nextjs project Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/vercel/path0/src/env.js' imported from /vercel/path0/next.config.js

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

I was trying to deploy a brand new Nextjs project on Vercel and this error happened.

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/vercel/path0/src/env.js' imported from /vercel/path0/next.config.js

I tried:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push origin main
```